# How to always show handsontable suggestions, even when value is specified

Tags: handsontable

I have a handsontable object using autocomplete (dropdown).  When a table cell is empty, and I click on the cell, it shows a dropdown of suggestions.

After I enter a value in that cell, when I click on the arrow, it only shows me one suggestion, that which is already in the cell.

How do I see all of the suggestions, even when there is a value in the cell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently doing this is the solution:

```
new Handsontable(element, {
    ...
    filter: false,
    ...
});
```